# Display Google plus community post on web page

Tags: google-plus

I am using this method for embedding post on my webpage.

> The easiest method is to locate the post that you want to embed on plus.google.com and click the downward pointing arrow that indicates the menu menu icon and choose Embed post. dialog displays with code that you can copy and paste into the desired location within your article or site. For example:

[image: Post embed example code]

But i want to display a community post on my web page. Can anyone please explain the procedure to me?

Comment: oh well... Insert This Code Into Your Html.

Comment: but i am render the community post.

Comment: No you don't render it. the embeded javascript will render it. see the code ? it says "place this tag where you want the widget to render"

Comment: There is some problem with community post. May be restricted. "Community post is not rendering" I have same problem

Comment: i have one example link send https://plus.google.com/107505091494053426676/posts/2RDuYyyYrEc          How to This post is embed

Comment: Yup... There is no option for embedded post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google+ Embedded Posts](https://developers.google.com/+/web/embedded-post/)

> The following post types are not supported:
>
> - Posts from within a community, including publicly reshared posts from a community.

Comment: any way to this type of post display in my web page?